Problem regarding faces in a planar cubic graph
Let $G$ be connected planar cubic graph. Denote by $f_i$ the number of those faces of $G$ that are bounded with $i$ edges. Prove that $\sum_{i \geq 3}(6-i)f_i = 12$
Here's my attempt:
By HS: $\sum_{v \in V} d_v(G) = 3p =2q$, since the graph is cubic, each vertex has degree 3.
Then by using Euler's formula: $$p-q+f=2$$
$$p-\frac{2}{3}p+f=2$$
$$p+3f=6$$
But from here I have no idea what to do. Do I somehow have to estimate the maximum number of edges?

Hint : Any face bounded by $i$ edges is said to have degree $i$. What is the sum of degrees of all faces? Can you relate that to $\sum if_i$? For a second hint, what is $\sum f_i$?
